# Should I use std::shared pointer to pass a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, smart-pointers

Suppose I have an object which is managed by an `std::unique_ptr`. Other parts of my code need to access this object. What is the right solution to pass the pointer? Should I just pass the plain pointer by `std::unique_ptr::get` or should I use and pass an `std::shared_ptr` instead of the `std::unique_ptr` at all?

I have some preference for the `std::unique_ptr` because the owner of that pointer is actually responsible for cleanup. If I use a shared pointer, there's a chance that the object will remain alive due to a shared pointer even when it should actually be destroyed.

EDIT: Unfortunately, I forgot to mention that the pointer will not just be a an argument to a function call, but it will be stored in other objects to build up a network structure of objects. I do not prefer the shared pointer because then it's no longer clear, who actually owns the object.

Comment: why not pass the reference of the unique_ptr object around?

Comment: You can't have a `unique_ptr` and a `shared_ptr` both manage the same object.

Comment: passing a reference to the referred object, is a good idea.

Comment: @Zaiborg a reference to a `unique_ptr` is only useful if you want to reseat the unique_ptr. If you only want to observe the pointer a raw pointer or reference is fine. A reference to a `unique_ptr` is no safer. See http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/.

Comment: I see your update - will respond in my answer

Comment: Do you also need to be able to re-seat these? If you never change which instance your network of objects refer to, use a reference. If you need to be able to point your existing object(s) at a different instance later, you need some kind of pointer.

Comment: I do not need to re-seat, but I can not necessarily set the reference, which will be a class member, upon construction.

Comment: My gut feeling is that you are in trouble no matter which implementation you choose if you can't guarantee that stale "references" (i.e. pointers or C++ references) are discarded before the object they refer to are destroyed. You could guard against that through weak_ptrs, which means your owner must use shared_ptrs iiuc. They would not prevent object destruction on the owner side the way ordinary shared_ptrs would, but still provide run time safety on the user side. In fact, you could use a failed weak_ptr access as a trigger to "garbage collect" that part of your data network structure.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If the ownership of the managed object is not being transferred (and because it's a `unique_ptr`, ownership cannot be shared) then it's more correct to separate the logic in the called function from the concept of ownership. We do this by calling by reference.

This is a convoluted way of saying:

Given:

```
std::unique_ptr<Thing> thing_ptr;
```

to change the Thing:

```
// declaration
void doSomethingWith(Thing& thing); 

// called like this
doSomethingWith(*thing_ptr);
```

to use the Thing without modifying it.

```
// declaration
void doSomethingWith(const Thing& thing); 

// called like this
doSomethingWith(*thing_ptr);
```

The only time you'd want to mention the `unique_ptr` in the function signature would be if you were transferring ownership:

```
// declaration
void takeMyThing(std::unique_ptr<Thing> p);

// call site
takeMyThing(std::move(thing_ptr));
```

You never need to do this:

```
void useMyThing(const std::unique_ptr<Thing>& p);
```

The reason that this would be a bad idea is that if confuses the logic of useMyThing with the concept of ownership, thus narrowing the scope for re-use.

Consider:

```
useMyThing(const Thing& thing);

Thing x;
std::unique_ptr<Thing> thing_ptr = makeAThing();
useMyThing(x);
useMyThing(*thing_ptr);
```

Update:

Noting the update to the question - storing (non-owning) references to this object.

One way to do this is indeed to store a pointer. However, pointers suffer from the possibility of a logic error in that they can legally be null. Another problem with pointers is that they do not play nicely with `std:: algorithms` and containers - requiring custom compare functions and the like.

There is a `std::-compliant` way to do this - the `std::reference_wrapper<>`

So rather than this:

```
std::vector<Thing*> my_thing_ptrs;
```

do this:

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Thing>> my_thing_refs;
```

Since `std::reference_wrapper<T>` defines an operator `T&`, you can use the `reference_wrapped` object in any expression that would expect a `T`.

for example:

```
std::unique_ptr<Thing> t1 = make_thing();
std::unique_ptr<Thing> t2 = make_thing();
std::unique_ptr<Thing> t3 = make_thing();

std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<const Thing>> thing_cache;

store_thing(*t1);
store_thing(*t2);
store_thing(*t3);

int total = 0;
for(const auto& t : thing_cache) {
  total += value_of_thing(t);
}
```

where:

```
void store_thing(const Thing& t) {
  thing_cache.push_back(std::cref(t));
}

int value_of_thing(const Thing& t) {
  return <some calculation on t>;
}
```

Comment: This is a very good answer, thanks a lot! Unfortunately, I forgot to point out one important fact, which I now edited into my post.

Comment: @Michael I think even if the other parts of the code wish to hold on to the reference this advice still stands. As long as you can ensure the other parts of the code will not use it after the `unique_ptr` has been destroyed. If you can't ensure that then a `unique_ptr` is not appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

Typically you would just pass a reference or plain pointer to other parts of the code that wish to observe the object.

Pass by reference:

```
void func(const Foo& foo);

std::unique_ptr<Foo> ptr;

// allocate ptr...

if(ptr)
    func(*ptr);
```

Pass by raw pointer:

```
void func(const Foo* foo);

std::unique_ptr<Foo> ptr;

// allocate ptr...

func(ptr.get());
```

The choice will depend on the need to pass a null pointer.

It is your responsibility to ensure by-design that observers do not use the pointer or reference after the `unique_ptr` has been destroyed. If you can't guarantee that then you must use a `shared_ptr` instead of a `unique_ptr`. Observers can hold a `weak_ptr` to indicate that they do not have ownership.

EDIT: Even if observers wish to hold on to the pointer or reference that is OK but it does make it more difficult to ensure it will not be used after the `unique_ptr` has been destroyed.

Comment: I think you touch the problem here with "your responsibility". Holding refs to possibly deceased objects is a sign of bad communication (the data structure should be informed that an element has been deleted). And indeed, a weak_ptr may be a cheap way out.

Answer (score 4):

Don't focus so much on the caller's requirements. What does the function need to be passed in? If it's only going to use the object for the duration of the call, then use a reference.

```
void func(const Foo& foo);
```

If it needs to retain ownership of the object past its duration, then pass in a `shared_ptr`

```
void func(std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo);
```

Comment: The last part could be more clear given that the question starts with "Suppose I have an object which is managed by an std::unique_ptr".

Answer (score 3):

Since the question update, I'd prefer:

1. `std::reference_wrapper<>` as suggested by Richard Hodges, so long as you don't require the option of NULL values.

   Note that your use case does seem to require a default constructor though, so this is out unless you have some public static instance to use as default.
2. some custom `not_your_pointer<T>` type with the required semantics: default-constructable, copyable and assignable, convertible from `unique_ptr` and non-owning. Probably only worthwhile if you're using it a lot though, since writing a new smart pointer class requires some thought.
3. if you need to handle dangling references gracefully, use `std::weak_ptr` and change ownership to a `shared_ptr` (That is, only *one* shared_ptr exists: there's no ambiguity about ownership and object lifetime is unaffected)

---

Before the question update, I preferred:

1. indicate that ownership is not transferred by passing a reference:

   ```
   void foo(T &obj); // no-one expects this to transfer ownership
   ```

   called as:

   ```
   foo(*ptr);
   ```

   you do lose the ability to pass `nullptr` though, if that matters.
2. indicate that ownership is not transferred by explicitly prohibiting it:

   ```
   void foo(std::unique_ptr<T> const &p) {
       // can't move or reset p to take ownership
       // still get non-const access to T
   }
   ```

   this is clear, but does expose your memory management policy to the callee.
3. pass a raw pointer and document that ownership *should not* be transferred. This is the weakest and most error prone. Don't do it.

Comment: What does a `const unique_ptr&` offer that a raw pointer does not? And as you say, the downside is it exposes your memory management policy?

Comment: const-ref-to-unique_ptr makes the code explicitly document, and guarantee, the contract.  It's unlikely the callee will come to think they're supposed (or allowed) to take ownership, and they'll have to use `const_cast`  or some other hack to get it. And unlike the raw reference, you can still pass `nullptr`.

Comment: @Useless: Nothing in the `const unique_ptr&` specification prevents obtaining the underlying raw pointer through `p.get()`, and doing whatever one wants with that (storing in a data structure is what OP intends). And the default assumption in passing a raw pointer or a reference would be that ownership is not transferred (consider all those functions taking `const char*`), so option 2 is really not buying you much. The main point is very clearly documenting that a pointer is not owned at the place where it gets stored.

Comment: Sure, but if you receive a (const ref to) `unique_ptr`, that pretty effectively documents that _someone else already owns the object_. You can circumvent it, but you'd have to be perverse not to realise you're deliberately breaking the contract. Conversely, receiving a raw pointer gives no information at all about who is supposed to clean this thing up, and increases the risk someone will honestly believe they're supposed to take ownership.

Comment: I agree with @Useless here. Any feature can be circumvented, but that doesn't mean we should stop using them. Plus 1.

Comment: I think a raw pointer should already document that ownership should not be transferred.  If I wanted to document that ownership should be transferred I would have passed a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: You may quite reasonably think that, but there's enough legacy code which uses raw pointers to (sometimes) transfer ownership, that it seems optimistic to depend on everyone else sharing your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

This ground has already been covered by Herb Sutter in [GotW #91 - Smart Pointer Parameters](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/).
It touches on the performance aspect as well, whilst the other answers, while great, focus on memory management.

Someone above recommended passing a smart pointer as const reference - changed his mind in later edit. We had code where this was abused - it made the signatures 'smarter' - i.e. more complicated but no benefit. The worst is when a junior developer takes over - he would not question as @Michael and 'learn' how to do it from a bad example. It works, but...

To me the smart pointer parameter passing matter is serious enough to be mentioned prominently in any book/article/post immediately after explaining what smart pointers are.

Wondering now if lint-like programs should flag passing by const reference as element of style.